# Менять изображение при наведении на ссылку

Tags: javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать смену  изображения при наведении на ссылку. И что бы когда курсор убирали со ссылки  - изображение менялось на исходное.

Смену при наведении делаю с помощью кода:

```
$("#catalog").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#menu-hover").attr("src","/themes/img/menu-hover.png");
});
```

А как определять то что курсор убрали со ссылки не понял...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать и с помощью CSS. Например так:

```
#elementid:hover {
 background-image: url(image_hover.format);
}
#elementid {
 background-image: url(image_normal.format);
}
```

Но если нужно именно JavaScript, то можно использовать события mouseover/mouseout. Например так:

```
var mouseListeners = {
 mouseover : function (event) {
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  target.setAttribute("src", "image_hover.format");
 },

 mouseout : function (event) {
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  target.setAttribute("src", "image_normal.format");
 }
}

element.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseListeners.mouseover);
element.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseListeners.mouseout);
```

Если же нужно использовать jQuery, воспользуйтесь функцией mouseleave(). Например так:

```
$("#elementid").mouseout(function() {
    $("#elementid2").attr("src","image_normal.format");
});
```

Comment: спасибо. mouseout  то что нужно было!

Comment: @Денис обновил ответ для jQuery.